# Eclipse Luna debug slow only up to the very first breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

Reading through Eclipse debug topics I did not find an answer to my specific problem. I wonder if anybody else has seen it. I only experience this since switching to Luna, I used Kepler and Indigo before.

I usually debug Tomcat, but it happens for any one-class test app. When the app hits the first breakpoint, Debug view is shown, then I have to wait 20-30 seconds for the debugger to initialize, and only then is the code line highlighted in the editor. From that point on every break is immediate. Other kind of slowness is not experienced. In Tomcat any subsequent request stops quickly. The problem is that it's restarted often when hot code replacement is not feasible.

Anybody knows how to tweak it? There is no building or validating process going on at that time, and I tried to allocate various amounts of memory to Eclipse. -Xms256m, -Xmx2048m usually works very well for me.

Comment: I have the same issue. Running Luna on Win7 64, Tomcat 8, Java 1.8.0_05, Eclipse/OS on SSD, webapp deployed to ramdisk. Still have plenty of memory free. Debugging by connecting to Tomcat using Java Remote Application configuration. Don't recall this happening under Kepler.

Comment: Same for me since upgrading to Luna, except the delay is only about 5 seconds.

Comment: According to bug reports the delay may depend on the number of libs used by the project. Ours has around 300 jars of different sizes. The question is why the initilization cannot take place in the background before I start to debug, and if its results could be cached...

Comment: In my case (Tomcat 7, Java 7, Eclipse Luna)  I had the same issue when placing breakpoint on line with the method signature. To be precise it must have been signature of the overriden method in annonymout class. The debugging slowed down and I had to wait 30 - 40 seconds. When I placed the breakpoint to the line where was method body, the debugging worked with no delay.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My issue was fixed in Luna SR1.

Comment: I'm running Luna SR1 and I still see this issue.

Comment: I'm running Luna SR2, and I just ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing all breakpoints worked for me too. Probably it was because of that breakpoint in jar files it would be taking more time for generating line numbers for those files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to tweak it, but in experiencing the same problem I found an Eclipse bug ticket already created for this along with duplicates: 440470 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440470).

Starting Eclipse with "-consolelog -debug" hasn't showed any additional errors related to this.

I am working with a large core Java project and have also installed EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework) and GEF (Graphical Editor Framework) plugin packages and dependencies via update site.  I have installed these in previous versions of Eclipse without the debug delay issue.  I tried closing this project and created a new test project with a simple Java class.  There was no delay when debugging this class.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post trying solve my issue: Very very slow to initialize tomcat, hibernate, etc. If you fall down here for similar problem I would suggest you what resolved to me. Try:

- Clear all breakpoints, mainly those in API's, clear expressions too.

That's what worked for me.

Comment: Actually, it does suggest a solution that worked for the author in a remotely similar situation (slowness issues). While it might not be the solution for the author's actual problem (which was solved in Luna SR1), it is a possible solution for those who are searching for related problems (which is how Eder Marques found the question).